# Export database (only data) with Laravel 4

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to find a package or method which allow me to export all the data from my database (SQL) in order to backup the database.

The goal is to have a button to save the database in a SQL file and download it, so i need a method in a controller to export the data.

I found nothing on http://packalyst.com/packages

Is somebody knows a way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package - which is an excellent backup manager:

https://github.com/heybigname/backup-manager

If you want it to be accessible via a controller - you can just call the artisan command from your controller:

```
function someControllerFunction()
{
    Artisan::call('db:backup');
}
```