# Backup and download .sql file Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

A project i am currently working on requires the ability to export the full database with a click of a button in an admin area of a website. I know theres plenty of packages out there for automatic backups to dropbox etc.. But thats not what is required for this project.

I was just wondering is there a fast and easy way to just dump the full database in laravel 4?

I can handle the zipping and downloading of the file once its been dumped just wondering if theres an easy way to dump a database with laravel 4.

Any help appriciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26421648/3892935

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although packages like https://github.com/heybigname/backup-manager are perfect for backing up a database. They offer a lot more than i needed for this particular project.

In the end i used https://github.com/bradcornford/Backup which is a great package for backing up your database on the fly with one simple method.